# Error: format string is not a string literal

Tags: c, string, gcc

I have written a simple program in C, which allocates memory for a string vector and then prints this.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char str_a[20];

    strcpy(str_a, "Hello, world!\n");
    printf(str_a);
}
```

Using compiler `gcc`, this gives a compilation error:

```
char_array2.c:8:12: warning: format string is not a string literal
      (potentially insecure) [-Wformat-security]
    printf(str_a);

1 warning generated.
```

I do not understand why I am getting a warning. Can someone explain it to me?

Comment: The message tells you exactly what's going on. What don't you understand in it?

Comment: "1 warning generated." != "a compilation error".

Comment: A warning is not the same thing as an error.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Use:

```
printf("%s", str_a);
```

to get rid of the warning when `-Wformat-security` is enabled.

The diagnostic is informative to avoid [format string vulnerability](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Format_string_attack). For example:

```
strcpy(str_a, "%x%x%x%x");
printf(str_a);
```

would be equivalent to:

```
printf("%x%x%x%x");
```

which is missing the required arguments and can be used by an attacker to dump the stack (assuming `str_a` is under user control, which is not the case in your program, but `gcc` is not smart enough to figure).

Answer (score 9):

Consider 3 `printf()` statements.  Which can the compiler detect if a format mis-match exists?

```
void foo(const char *str_a,int x) {
  printf("Hello %d\n", x);  // Compiler sees this is good
  printf("Hello %d\n");     // Compiler sees this is bad --> warning/error
  printf(str_a, x);         // Compiler cannot tell - thus the warning
}
```

Answer (score 8):

The other answers are better.  But if all else fails, you can tell the compiler to ignore the error.

```
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wformat"
printf(str_a);
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
```

[godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/ex1scc56q)

Comment: Eeek. No :) Some warnings are supposed to be read and acted upon, not ignored to allow for sloppy code, and the last thing you want in C is sloppy code...

Answer (score 3):

This is not an error but a warning. When using printf to print a string you want something like `printf("%s", str_a)`. Whenever you have a string in quotes (" ") it's a string literal this is what the warning means when it says not a string literal. I am not completely sure why you need to have a string literal but it is usually best to follow the compiler; someone else can probabally clarify the need for a string literal.

Answer (score 3):

If you were to do something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char str_a[20];

    fgets(str_a, 20, stdin);
    printf(str_a);
}
```

And the user entered in `A %s bad %n string`, the user will be able to crash your program, and perhaps start a shell.

With this input, the user can effectively do this:

```
printf("A %s bad %n string");
```

The `%s` specifier causes the function to read from an invalid address, while the `%n` specifier causes it to *write* to an invalid address.

Answer (score 0):

The warning is issued because good compilers compare the format specifiers like `%d` in the format string against the types (here an `int`) following the format. This obviously only works for string literals that the compiler can analyze for specifiers. A pointer-to-char in a variable defeats this sanity check of types.

Note that non-matching format specifiers (or argument types) cause **undefined behavior** and often lead to garbage values being converted or crashes. Think about what happens when a `%s` is associated with an integral value.